# Is it possible to add a whitespace to a system library header?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I have a problem compiling application in c++11 mode that can be resolved by simply adding a whitespace character into the header of dbus library.

If I do this - will it break stuff when the library I am trying to build (with whitespace'd header)  will try to link to dbus (which was built without whitespace in the header) ?

In particular, dbus-protocol.h contains this line:

```
#define DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_DOCTYPE_DECL_NODE "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC \""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER"\"\n\""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER"\">\n"
```

where, to successfuly compile in c++11 mode whitespace must be inserted as in:

```
...PUBLIC \"" DBUS_INTROSPECT...
```

How much can we really change in a header file without breaking compatibility? 
(I know of qt ABI compatibility guide but I don't think it addresses my particular question)

Comment: It is difficult to say. I would think normally that adding a whitespace in a header file will not do anything, but you say it fixes your problem. Post the code (before your change and after your change) and then we will understand what you are asking to a good-enough level, to be able to answer. Also, your question is tagged linux and dll. There are no dlls under linux.

Comment: After your edit, yes that whitespace is required in C++11 and won't break anything.

Comment: And why is it neccessary?

Comment: @TomásBadan because `DBUS_INTROSPECT` is interpreted as a user defined literal, even by the preprocessor.

Comment: @Simple Thanks, I'll do a deep look

Comment: that generates warning, at least on g++4.8.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a bug in that header.  Barring some really pathological cases, adding whitespace there will not cause incompatibility, other than avoiding the bug on some compilers.

I am assuming that the `DBUS_`... identifier expands to a quote delimited string, which is then supposed to auto concatinate with the rest of that macro.  It is a pretty safe assumption.

Comment: This is fixed in later versions of dbus as far as I know, but I don't want delving into manually reinstalling the library if it is possible to simply insert the whitespace and be done with it :)